# Why (or when) are RV 50 amp to 30 amp adapters okay

Tags: electrical

I'm getting a travel trailer with 30 amp service. Camping forums often suggest getting a 50 amp to 30 amp adapter so that, if a campground has 50 amp service but no 30 amp service (or a broken 30 amp receptacle), the trailer can still be plugged in. Using the adapter, it seems to me like it is possible to send 50 amps over the camper's 30 amp cord and that should lead to fires or melting. I'm trying to understand why this isn't happening.

The usual justification is that, because the camper has a 30 amp internal breaker and is designed for 30 amps, it just can't pull more than 30 amps and therefore there is no threat to the system.

Sometimes one sees an additional suggestion to run a fancy surge protector with an emergency-power-off (EPO) feature that will disconnect power if it detects too many amps (or volts).

So I can imagine these configurations:

#### No surge protector

RV 30 amp breaker <- 30 amp cord <- 50 amp to 30 amp adapter <- 50 amp receptacle

If the RV breaker trips, there was a brief time where more than 30 amps were passing through the 30 amp cord. Too brief to be able to cause a problem?

#### Surge protector

RV 30 amp breaker <- 30 amp cord <- 30 amp EPO surge protector <- adapter <- 50 amp receptacle

The EPO shuts down the circuit if more than 30 amps move through it. The 30 amp cord cannot be exposed to 50 amps and is therefore safe?

### So... safe or not?

I can find (a lot of) random articles online asserting this is safe. I can also find a handful asserting that it is not safe. I'd like to be completely convinced this is safe before buying the adapter.

Comment: If the device you're purchasing has a (real) UL listing, you should be fine. If you're buying it from the site named after a big river, there's a significant chance that it does _NOT_ have that UL listing. ETL is also acceptable, but easier to fake than UL - UL should come with a number that you can look up to prove that it's legit, AIUI, ETL does not. If there's a breaker in the trailer, then yes, it _should_ trip prior to there being too much power for too long running through your adapter. If not, then you could pull 50a for hours and burn the trailer and the 50a breaker will never trip.

Comment: A surge protector is not a circuit breaker (unless it is).  The circuit breaker protection should be inside the 50A-30A adapter, which is required to have a circuit breaker or fuse for that very reason.  UL permits an adapter with a non-replaceable fuses which becomes plastic waste when overloaded once.  UL writes safety rules, not environmental or pro-consumer rules.  Do NOT under any circumstances use an adapter that does not have a molded-in UL listing or other recognized NRTL. Most mail order sites sell absolute junk, due to a cleverly arranged set of loopholes in our product-safety laws.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 50 to 30A adapter (by itself) is ok when the adapter has an integrated fuse that will prevent more than 30 amps from flowing for an extended period of time. This doesn't need to be fancy, any decent quality fuse will do.

In context of plugging in another device that has its own overcurrent protection, they are fine as long as that overcurrent protection is adequate for 30A.

The overcurrent protection only needs to be present on one side of the wire to protect the circuit. However if the wire is susceptible to damage it is better to put the protection on the load side of the vulnerable area.

Comment: This. Any LISTED adapter will have a fuse or breaker inbuilt at the adapter - because the cord being plugged into the adapter isn't rated for 50A.

Comment: The fuse is something I wanted to ask about but felt too different to fit into the question. It also feels too small to be another question. :)

Are _only_ fused adapters acceptable? There simply are no adapters with resettable breakers?